# Como fazer uma conversão implícita (herança) sem perder informações

Tags: java

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto para faculdade onde tenho que implementar 3 classes. Essas classes herdam uma da outra como no modelo abaixo:

```
public class AssinanteFree {
    protected int id;
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int v) { id = v; }

    protected String nome;
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public void setNome(String v) { nome = v; }
}

public class AssinantePremium extends AssinanteFree {
    protected double pontos;
    public double getPontos(){ return pontos; }
    public void setPontos(double v) { pontos = v; }
}

public class AssinanteVip extends AssinantePremium {
    protected String criadoEm;
    public String getCriadoEm() { return criadoEm; }
    public void setCriadoEm(String v) { criadoEm = v; }
}
```

Tenho que fazer a persistência dos objetos criados em um arquivo, sendo assim criei um arquivo que simula uma base de dados, assim:

```
public class Db {
    // construtores
    private Db() {
        assinantes = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    private Db(int i) throws IOException {
        try {
            get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            assinantes = new ArrayList<>();
            set();
        }
    }
    // implementação singleton
    private static Db instance;
    public static Db getInstance() throws IOException {
        return instance == null ? instance = new Db(0) : instance;
    }
    // getters & setters
    private ArrayList<AssinanteFree> assinantes;
    public ArrayList<AssinanteFree> getAssinantes() {
        return instance.assinantes;
    }
    public void setAssinantes(ArrayList<AssinanteFree> v) {
        assinantes = v;
    }
    // persistencia
    private void get() throws IOException {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("db.json")) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            instance = gson.fromJson(reader, Db.class);
        }
    }
    private void set() throws IOException {
        try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("db.json")) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            gson.toJson(this, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Meu problema é o seguinte, se no meu "banco de dados" eu tiver um tipo `AssinanteFree` para a lista `assinantes`, quando a classe salva em arquivo ela não salva as outras propriedades das classes extendidas e, Se eu persisto a classe mais profunda na herança, ao fazer uma consulta dos dados tenho que ficar convertendo os mesmos.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode simular que no seu banco existem 3 tabelas (3 diferentes `ArrayList`), uma para cada tipo de assinante e cada tabela precisa ter um `id`, e o `id` delas **deve ser o mesmo** se fizerem parte do mesmo relacionamento.

Ao salvar apenas `AssinanteFree`, você apenas insere o registro na tabela de AssinanteFree. Ao inserir um `AssinantePremium`, você insere os registros que pertencem apenas ao AssinantePremium na tabela de AssinantePremium e as informações de AssinanteFree na tabela AssinanteFree, com o mesmo id. A mesma ideia aplica-ase ao `AssinanteVip`.

Portanto, ao inserir um registro de `AssinantePremium`, ficará assim no seu "banco de dados":

```
# AssinantePremium
id  | pontos
123 | 4

# AssinanteFree
id  | nome
123 | Leandro
```

E ao inserir mais um assinante Premium:

```
# AssinantePremium
id  | pontos
123 | 4
456 | 7

# AssinanteFree
id  | nome
123 | Leandro
456 | Leonardo

# AssinanteVip
id  | criadoEm
456 | 2018-06-28
```

Outra ideia é usar a mesma "tabela" (com um único `ArrayList`). Você teria todos os campos de todos as classes em uma única tabela, mas saberia de qual classe ela pertence usando um `Tipo` para distinguir elas. O mesmo exemplo acima ficaria desta maneira:

```
# Assinante
id  | nome     | pontos | criadoEm    | Tipo
123 | Leandro  | 4      |             | AssinantePremium
456 | Leonardo | 7      | 2018-06-28  | AssinanteVip
```

Perceba que em ambos os casos você precisa "gravar" de uma maneira (quando vai para o seu `ArrayList`) e converter para outra, quando vai extrair o conteúdo dela e montar as classes.

As dicas acima são inspiradas em como o JPA/Hibernate trata as mesmas situações.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi... então em teoria tenho 3 ArrayList's onde no primeiro tenho o `AssinanteFree`, no segundo tenho o complemento do `AssinantePremium` e no terceiro tenho o complemento do `AssinanteVip`?

Comment: Na minha primeira ideia, sim, cada uma simulando uma tabela. Estou escrevendo uma outra ideia agora com apenas uma única tabela.

Comment: Porque a princípio eu tava fazendo com somente 1 tabela, o problema é que ao fazer a conversão inversa não ficava muito "legal"

Comment: Creio que se eu realmente fizer como você diz fica melhor... porque assim se eu quiser realmente saber o tipo da pessoa, ou eu posso pesquisar nos outros ArrayLists o id ou eu posso adicionar um campo tipo no free... assim resolve o problema...

Comment: Editei e acrescentei outra opção, usando um mesmo ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Com base no que o @dherik falo, a minha solução foi uma mistura dos 2 modelos, assim:

1º adicionei um campo tipo ao `AssinanteFree` e um construtor à cada classe definindo esse tipo, assim:

```
public class AssinanteFree {
    public AssinanteFree(String tipo){ 
        this.tipo = tipo == null || !tipo.equals("") ? "Free" : tipo; 
    }
    protected String tipo;
    public String getTipo(){ return tipo; }
    // ...
}

public class AssinantePremium extends AssinanteFree {

    public AssinantePremium(String tipo) { 
        super(tipo == null || !tipo.equals("") ? "Premium" : tipo);
    }
    // ...
}

public class AssinanteVip extends AssinantePremium {

    public AssinanteVip(){
        super("Vip");
    }
// ...
}
```

2º criei defini meu `ArrayList` no Db como todo mundo sendo do tipo Vip isso para poder simular a estrutura de tabelas:

Agora, em todo caso eu sempre vou trabalhar com a class Assinantes Vip mas, dependendo do tipo daquele assinante e onde eu estiver usando, eu vou fazer a conversão implícita. O bom de usar assim é que eu ainda posso adicionar mais um método a classe `Db` onde eu pego o Get com base em um filtro, assim:

```
public class Db {
    // ...
    public ArrayList<AssinanteVip> getAssinantes(String tipo) {
        return (ArrayList)instance.assinantes.stream()
                   .filter((a)-> a.tipo.equals(tipo))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    // ...
}
```